# What is the right way to realize a large web app

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, web-applications, scalability

I have to realize a web app able to guarantee two main actions execution:

first one action is about allowing to a small number of users to upload ads or posts, these A users will can upload ads in the application as they will want but they will can upload photos until five megabyte overall threshold. Moreover ads total number will be approximately 10k.

Second action is about allowing to a broad public (1k users per day) to looking for and check published articles from A users, these research will can be more accurate inserting advanced filters.

I would like to know if is strictly necessary build up my app in a scalable way  or if I could simply use a MVC approach?
This app will be developed using Laravel framework and it will hosted by Amazon server.
what do you recommend me to do ?

I would like to have some advices, tips and tricks to do it in the best way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC approach is fine, Laravel, or any platform, can be scaled in multiple ways. The simplest is separating the functions of DB, laravel app, cache, queue, to separate servers, and each of those pieces can be scaled separately.

There is a great online set of videos about this, [https://serversforhackers.com/scaling-laravel/forge.](https://serversforhackers.com/scaling-laravel/forge)

But unless you know you will have a large amount of traffic right away, it's better to start with a simpler structure, you will save on cost and it's not hard to scale it later. I mean, start with one server for now, then maybe separate the functions (cache, DB etc) to separate servers as you find they need to be scaled.

If you want to save a little hassle though, I do recommend Laravel [Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/), and [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/). It makes deploying and managing servers a lot easier. Envoyer is for deployments, great to automate all that.

Comment: Great answer. A video that reinforces a lot of this is Jeffrey Way's 'Things Laravel Made Me Believe': https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDotS5BDqRM